# Linux command to find and delete certain files, but output the result or verbose mode?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

So I use these command on my storage server to clean up some junk, but it doesn't produce any output or result. I found the syntax online somewhere and just modified for which files I need it. What else do I need to add to see what is actually being deleted or total at the end? Ultimately this would be a script that will run automatically but for right now I'm running the commands manually. Thanks in advance!

```
find . -name .DS_Store -printf \"%p\"\ \  | xargs rm 
find . -name ._.DS_Store -printf \"%p\"\ \  | xargs rm 
find . -name Thumbs.db -printf \"%p\"\ \  | xargs rm
find . -name ._Thumbs.db -printf \"%p\"\ \  | xargs rm
```

Comment: Is anything wrong with just changing `rm` to `rm -v`?

Answer (score 18):

`find` also has a `-delete` flag.  And you could also combine everything into one command, possibly saving some time:

```
find . \( -name .DS_Store -or -name ._.DS_Store -or -name Thumbs.db -or -name ._Thumbs.db \) -print -delete
```

Comment: `find -print -delete` is really the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the -v parameter to the rm command for verbose output, e.g.

```
find . -name .DS_Store -printf \"%p\"\ \  | xargs rm -v
```

Answer (score 0):

The print parameter can be used to show all matched files:

```sh
find . -print
```